# How to programmatically add a label in a custom subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, drawrect

I'm designing a card game (cards against humanity) for iOS, there are two types of cards, the whites ones, and the black ones. So I've implemented a CardView class which inherits from UIView, and two class, WhiteCardView and BlackCardView which both inherit from CardView.
As you guess, almost only the color will change between those two, but I still want two different view class for those two (even if they are almost the same at the moment). So, I have four questions about that.

**EDIT**: I mnage to find out some answer by myself, but for the last one, I'm lost.

1.I need advice on my implementation, I don't know if I'm doing it right to set the colors of the cards which is stored in CardView but set in the init of my WhiteCardView. I think I have to override only one init, but I don't know which one. So if someone can confirm or correct what I already did, that would be great. Thanks

Here is my CardView code:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CardView : UIView

-(void)customDrawUI;
-(void)setData;

@property (nonatomic) UIColor* IBInspectable secondaryColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor* IBInspectable primaryColor;
@property(nonatomic) UILabel* txtLabel;

@end


@implementation CardView

-(void)customDrawUI{
    self.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
    self.backgroundColor = self.primaryColor;
}

-(void)setData{
    self.txtLabel.text = @"some text";
}
@end
```

And the WhiteCardView code:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface WhiteCardView : CardView
@end


@implementation WhiteCardView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect myFrame = self.bounds;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGRectInset(myFrame, 5, 5);
    [self.secondaryColor set];
    UIRectFrame(myFrame);
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.primaryColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.secondaryColor= [UIColor blackColor];
        [super customDrawUI];
        [super setData];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

2.In interface builder (where I correctly define the custom class for each of my cards), my views aren't live rendered, the code in my drawRect method WhiteCardView is executed but I can see no change.
And when I run my app, I get the same result. Just white rectangle, without any rounded angle.
Any idea why there is no changing in my view?

**EDIT**: I didn't put the IBDESIGNABLE tag in the right place, now it works !

3.Is there any way to execute that line: `self.backgroundColor = self.primaryColor;` in the parent drawRect method ? Because it's currently in both: White and BlackCardView, and there is certainly a way to do it in the parent class (I'll add common code to those two class, so I need a way to do it). 
Maybe it's possible to do this in the init from CardView, but as it's not working at the moment, I can't test it.

**EDIT**: I find out, the setBackground couldn't be called from drawRect, so I define a new method in the CardView class to do that. And I call it from the init methods.

4.The most important part: how is it possible to add a label on each card (not via interface builder but via the CardView class), and be able to set its content programmatically?
I defined a property for that label, and I set its value but I have no idea how to render it.

Comment: There is no reason for your `drawRect:` method. You aren't; drawing any custom content. Set the corner radius and background color once in the `init` method. Your other `init...` methods should then call `init`. Don't repeat the same code in all 3 `init...` methods.

Comment: I will later, to define border